# Executable suddenly stopped working: silent exit, no errors, no nothing

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, executable, exit

I am facing a rather peculiar issue: I have a Qt C++ application that used to work fine. Now, suddenly I cannot start it anymore. No error is thrown, no nothing.

Some more information:

- Last line of output when application is started in debug mode with Visual Studio 2012:

> The program '[4456] App.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

- **Actual application code (= first line in main()) is never called or at least no breakpoints are triggered, so debugging is not possible.**
- The executable process for a few seconds appears in the process list and then disappears again.
- Win 7 x64 with latest Windows updates.
- The issues simultaneously appeared on two separate machines.
- Application was originally built with Qt 5.2.1. Today I test-wise switched to Qt 5.4.1. But as expected no change.
- No changes to source code were made. The issue also applies to existing builds of the application.
- Running DependencyWalker did not yield anything of interest from my point of view.

I am flat out of ideas. Any pointers on what to try or look at? How can an executable suddenly stop working at all with no error?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not possible since the application's code is never triggered and therefore no debugger gets invoked. I already tried setting breakpoint in the first line in the main() method, but that one is never reached. Application seems to exit before.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier _"... application's code is never triggered ..."_ _`The program '[4456] App.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`_ what makes you think so?? The error message actually speaks against your theory!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would assume that if the code actually gets executed my breakpoint in the first code line should also be triggered, shouldn't it? I do use a few singletons, but each of them is independent. Also given that the same code as well as the existing EXE builds used to work, any idea why their behavior might suddenly change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the reason for this behavior...sort of. The coding (e. g. my singletons) were never the problem (as I expected since the code always worked). Instead an external library (SAP RFC SDK) caused the troubles.

This library depends on the ICU Unicode libraries and apparently specific versions at that. Since I wasn't aware of that fact, I only had the ICU libraries that my currently used Qt version needs in my application directory. The ICU libraries for the SAP RFC SDK must have been loaded from a standard windows path so far.

In the end some software changes (Windows updates, manual application uninstalls, etc.) must have removed those libraries which resulted in that described silent fail. Simply copying the required ICU library version DLLs into my application folder, solved the issue.

The only thing I am not quite sure about, is why this was not visible when tracing the loaded DLLs via DependencyWalker.

Comment: The ICU libraries are not linked into libsapucum.dll at link time, but loaded dynamically at runtime via WIN32 API LoadLibrary(). -- Therefore DependencyWalker doesn't find anything! -- If the LoadLibrary() does not find the correct version of the ICU DLLs, libsapucum.dll simply aborts the process. (Not sure, what SAP is thinking here...)  All this happens during load-time of the executable and its DLLs, before the operating system jumps into your main()...

Answer (score 0):

> *"**Actual application code (= first line in main()) is never called. So debugging is not possible.**"*

You probably have some static storage initialization failing, that's applied before `main()` is called.

Do you use any interdependent singletons in your code? Consolidate them to a single *singleton* if so (remember, there shouldn't be more than **one** singleton).

---

<sub>Also note, debugging still is possible well for such situation, the trap is ,- for such case as described in my answer -, `main()`'s bodies' first line is set as the first break point as default, when you start up your program in the debugger.

Nothing hinders you to set breakpoints, that are hit before starting up the code reaches `main()` actually.</sub>

---

As for your clarification from comments:

> *"I do use **a few** singletons ..."*

As mentioned above, if you are really sure you need to use a singleton, use actually a **single one**.

Otherwise you may end up, struggling with undefined order of initialization of static storage.

Anyway, it doesn't matter that much if static storage data depends on each other, provide a **single access point** to it throughout your code, to avoid cluttering it with heavy coupling to a variety of instances.

Coupling with a single instance, makes it easier to refactor the code to go with an interface, if it turns out *singleton* wasn't one.

Comment: Is there any way to debug those static initializations (ideally with Visual Studio) to get a handle were the issue is stemming from? I already set breakpoints in most constructors, to rule that out, but none are hit so far. And if that is really the issue, I am wondering why this issue is suddenly appearing, because as I said the same code worked flawlessly for a long time.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier As mentioned, just set breakpoints in your _songletons_ constructors, or where they are initialized.

Comment: I already tried that, but - again - non are triggered unfortunately.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier IIRC the technique I described works well with Visual Studio as well. Please update your question to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).